# Solving analitically this simple ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I could not find with maple an explicit analytical solution (i.e. not involving complicated integrals) to this simple ODE:

$\frac{d h(x)}{dx}+C =  -\frac{h(x)}{x^2} $

where C is a constant. Is it me not being able to use MAPLE or is there not such a solution? Thanks
A.

Comment: Just use an [integrating factor.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)

Comment: The solution to this equation involves $\mathrm{Ei}\left(\frac{-1}{x}\right)$ in an essential way.  ("Ei" is the exponential integral.)

Comment: [This web page](http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/lineareq/lineareq.html) may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite as $h'+x^{-2}h=C$ and use the [integrating factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) $\exp\left(\int x^{-2}\,dx\right)=e^{-x^{-1}}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
[h(x)e^{-x^{-1}}]'&=Ce^{-x^{-1}}\\
h(x)e^{-x^{-1}}&=\int Ce^{-x^{-1}}\,dx\\
h(x)&=e^{x^{-1}}\left(\int Ce^{-x^{-1}}\,dx+D\right)
\end{align}
$$

The integral there involves the e[xponential integral function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral), $\text{Ei}(z)$.

Comment: Thanks. I think that D should be also multiplied by e^(x^-1) correct? I dont understand why maple gives me a solution that looks like yours (after adding the correction I just mentioned) plus C*r. Where is this extra +C*r that maple gives coming from?

Comment: Yes, sorry I just didn't type the parentheses (but meant to). Fixed now.